# how do I create a row of bricks with geometry nodes?

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

[image]

[image]
[image]

How can I create another row of bricks? and make the seams the same when changing the size of the

Comment: There's a recent geometry nodes tutorial by Ryan King [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oE3GqhSd3NA) which might help. Incidentally the 'logic-bricks' tag is for the UPBGE game engine version of Blender and has nothing to do with creating walls! :^)